# Find Physical Device Object from Bug Check Message

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, bsod, device-manager

My machine crashed. The bug check was this:

```
The bugcheck was: 0x0000009f (0x0000000000000003, 0xffffe00000fca060, 0xffffd000201a5840, 0xffffe000014d3b60).
```

I searched for 0x9f and quickly located the description of it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559329(v=vs.85).aspx

It was that parameter two, `0xffffe00000fca060`, is the Physical Device Object of the stack.

How can I find what actual device that is referring to so I can go looking for updated drivers for that device? I go into Device Manager and look at the "Physical Device Object name" property of several devices, but none of them resemble `0xffffe00000fca060` or are even in that format.

Comment: Being an object stored in memory, you can't easily determine what it refers without a debugger. Check if you got any dump files in the `C:\Windows\Minidump` folder or a `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP` file. If that's the case, copy them to the desktop, compress everything into an archive, and upload it somewhere (e.g. http://ge.tt/about). Then post the link here for further diagnosis.

Comment: That makes sense... I feel silly for asking the question now. I'll dig through the dump. Thanks.